# Interaction between CheckboxButtonGroup and Legend in complex bokeh plot

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have a complex multivariate dataset that is similar in structure to this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from itertools import cycle, islice

N = 24
start_date = dt.date(2016,1,1)
nbdays = int(365 / N)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [start_date + dt.timedelta(days=i*nbdays) for i in range(1,N+1)], 
                   'Rating':    [(100/N)*i for i in range(1,N+1)], 
                   'Plot':      list(islice(cycle(range(1, 9)), 0, N)), 
                   'Treatment': list(islice(cycle(range(1, 7)), 0, N)), 
                   'Trial':     list(islice(cycle(range(1, 4)), 0, N)), 
                   'Name':      list(islice(cycle("ABCDEF"), 0, N)), 
                   'Target':    list(islice(cycle("JKLMNOP"), 0, N)), 
                   'Part':      list(islice(cycle("WXYZ"), 0, N)) 
                   })
```

I want:

- to plot `Date` versus `Rating`, colored by `Treatment`
- to have an interactive legend, so that clicking on a treatment toggles the visibility of the treatment
- to have buttons to the side of the plot for the other parameters (`Plot`, `Trial`, `Name`, `Target`, `Part`) so that clicking on a button toggles the visibility of corresponding dots
- to show all the parameters when you hover over a point

This is the code that I have (dataset from above in variable `df`):

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import Set1 
from bokeh.models import (CDSView, BooleanFilter, Legend,
                          DatetimeTickFormatter, Range1d,
                          HoverTool)
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxButtonGroup, Div
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, layout
from bokeh.io import curdoc

columns = ['Treatment', 'Plot', 'Trial', 'Name', 'Target', 'Part']
categories = [sorted(df[column].unique()) for column in columns]
all_columns = ['Date', 'Rating'] + columns

treatment_colormap = dict(zip(categories[0], Set1[6])) 

# Create Input controls
divs = [Div(text=column+':') for column in columns[1:]]
controls   = [CheckboxButtonGroup(labels=list(map(str, category)), active=list(range(len(category)))) for category in categories[1:]]

# Create Column Data Source that will be used by the plot
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict((column, []) for column in all_columns))


def select():
    actives = [control.active for control in controls]
    actives_names = [[category[a] for a in active] for (active, category) in zip(actives, categories[1:])]

    presence = [df[column].isin(active_names) for (column, active_names) in zip(columns[1:], actives_names)]
    result = df[np.logical_and.reduce(presence)] # https://stackoverflow.com/a/49027984/50065
    return result

def update():
    sdf = select()
    source.data = dict((column, sdf[column]) for column in all_columns)

    glyphs = []
    selected_treatments = sorted(sdf['Treatment'].unique())
    for treatment in selected_treatments:
        booleans = [value == treatment for value in source.data['Treatment']]
        view = CDSView(source=source, filters=[BooleanFilter(booleans)])
        color = treatment_colormap[treatment]
        glyphs.append(p.circle(x='Date', y='Rating', source=source, view=view, line_color=color, fill_color=color))

    legend = Legend(items=[
        ("treatment {}".format(treatment), [glyph]) for treatment, glyph
        in zip(selected_treatments, glyphs)
        ])

    p.add_layout(legend, 'below')
    p.legend.click_policy='hide'
    p.legend.location = 'bottom_center'
    p.legend.orientation = 'horizontal'

for control in controls:
    control.on_change('active', lambda attr, old, new: update())

def datetime_in_miliseconds(date):
    date = dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y')
    epoch = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
    return (date - epoch).total_seconds() * 1000.0

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Date', '@Date{%d/%m/%Y}')] + [(column, '@'+column) 
                            for column in all_columns[1:]], formatters={
                             'Date': 'datetime', # use 'datetime' formatter for 'Date' field
                             })


p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools=[hover])
p.title.text = 'Date vs Rating'
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Date'
p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(days = ['%d/%m/%y'])
start = datetime_in_miliseconds('01/01/2016')
end = datetime_in_miliseconds('31/12/2016')
p.x_range=Range1d(start, end)
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Rating'
p.ygrid.band_fill_color="olive"
p.ygrid.band_fill_alpha = 0.1
p.y_range=Range1d(0,100)

sizing_mode = 'scale_width'
inputs = widgetbox(*sum(zip(divs, controls), tuple()), sizing_mode=sizing_mode)

l = layout([[p, inputs]], sizing_mode=sizing_mode)
update()  # initial load of the data
curdoc().add_root(l)
```

which looks like this when you run `bokeh serve --show main.py` (`bokeh` version 0.12.10):

[image: plot]

What works:

- Clicking on the legend toggles the visibility of the treatments

What doesn't work:

- the information shown in the hoverlabels is incorrect (the first 6 dots have the same information in their hoverlabels, the next six dots also have identical hoverlabels and so on).
- clicking on the right hand buttons messes up the plot: axis labels dissapear, a second legend is show over the plot instead of below it)

How do I fix these last two points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some ideas:

- use `CustomJSFilter` to wrap a javascript function to do the data
  filter.
- use only one call of `p.circle()` to draw all the circles.
- use `factor_cmap` to map Treatment column to colors.
- use `tags`
  property to save data in Python and read it in javascript.

since there is only one `GlyphRenderer`, visibility toggle doesn't work with it's legend.

To solve this, create a dummy `ColumnDataSource` and call `p.circle()` many times with it to create a list of dummy `GlyphRenderer`.
Create legend for these dummy `GlyphRenderer`, and link their visible property change with a `CustomJS` that calls `source.change.emit()`
to redraw the figure.

Because all the filter calculation is executed by javascript, you can create a static html file that can interact with user inputs.

Here is the notebook:

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/ruoyu0088/01ddf28ed041508304843f49a794d66a

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, CDSView, CustomJSFilter, HoverTool
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxButtonGroup
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.palettes import Set1 
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, layout

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from itertools import cycle, islice

output_notebook()

N = 24
start_date = dt.date(2016,1,1)
nbdays = int(365 / N)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [start_date + dt.timedelta(days=i*nbdays) for i in range(1,N+1)], 
                   'Rating':    [(100/N)*i for i in range(1,N+1)], 
                   'Plot':      list(islice(cycle(range(1, 9)), 0, N)), 
                   'Treatment': list(islice(cycle(range(1, 7)), 0, N)), 
                   'Trial':     list(islice(cycle(range(1, 4)), 0, N)), 
                   'Name':      list(islice(cycle("ABCDEF"), 0, N)), 
                   'Target':    list(islice(cycle("JKLMNOP"), 0, N)), 
                   'Part':      list(islice(cycle("WXYZ"), 0, N)) 
                   })

columns = 'Plot', 'Trial', 'Name', 'Target', 'Part'
unique_items = [df[col].unique() for col in columns]

df["Treatment"] = df["Treatment"].astype(str)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)
dummy_source = ColumnDataSource(data={"x":[], "y":[]})

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Date', '@Date{%d/%m/%Y}')] + [(column, '@'+column) 
                            for column in columns], formatters={
                             'Date': 'datetime', # use 'datetime' formatter for 'Date' field
                             })

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools=[hover])
color = factor_cmap("Treatment", Set1[9], df.Treatment.unique())

for i, label in enumerate(df.Treatment.unique()):
    dummy_circle = p.circle(x="x", y="y", source=dummy_source, legend="Treatment {}".format(label), color=Set1[9][i])
    dummy_circle.tags = [label]

p.legend.location = "bottom_right"
p.legend.click_policy = "hide"

def source_change(source=source):
    source.change.emit()

callback_source_change = CustomJS.from_py_func(source_change)

for item in p.legend[0].items:
    item.renderers[0].js_on_change("visible", callback_source_change)

controls = [CheckboxButtonGroup(labels=items.astype(str).tolist(), active=list(range(len(items)))) for items in unique_items]
widgets = widgetbox(*controls)

for name, control in zip(columns, controls):
    control.tags = [name]

def func_filter(source=source, legend=p.legend[0], widgets=widgets):
    window.widgets = widgets
    visible_treatments = [item.renderers[0].tags for item in legend.items if item.renderers[0].visible]
    date = source.data['Date']
    treatments = source.data['Treatment']
    res = []

    selectors = {}
    for widget in widgets.children:
        col = widget.tags[0]
        selectors[col] = dict([(widget.labels[i], i) for i in widget.active])

    for i in range(len(date)):
        flag = treatments[i] in visible_treatments
        for key, val in selectors.items():
            if source.data[key][i] not in val:
                flag = False
                break
        res.append(flag)
    return res

view = CDSView(source=source, filters=[CustomJSFilter.from_py_func(func_filter)])
p.circle(x='Date', y='Rating', source=source, view=view, line_color=color, fill_color=color)  

for control in controls:
    control.js_on_change("active", callback_source_change)

show(layout([[p, widgets]]))
```

Comment: It was very good. I never knew callbacks works in notebook and in impression that I need to use bokeh server every time. Thank you it helped me. @HYRY